# Repeating items in an array multiple times in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array with 6 strings representing HTML image tags. I have some code which determines an amount of space to fill with these images.

I am using a loop, which works fine to pull from these 6 images and use 1 or all 6.  My issue comes when I need MORE than 6, which would mean go through the array again and again.  I am unsure how to best construct this loop.  Currently I have

```
for (var i = 0; i < numAds ; i++) {
            $('#primary').append(adList[i]);
        };
```

I tried adding `if (i > adList.length) { i=0 }` before the jquery statement but then I got stuck in a loop and crashed the browser.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
$('#primary').append(adList[i % adList.length]);
```

The `%` is the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29)

---

Make sure, though, that `adList` is not empty or that would cause the `i % adList.length` to return `NaN` and <strike>crash</strike> *make the `adList[i % adList.length]` return `undefined` what whatever sideffects this might bring*.

Comment: You can also remove `append` from loop.

Comment: If i = 0 would `i % adList.length` not result in `NaN` ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Ah yes, I got it the wrong way around `i % 0` would be `NaN`. Sorry about that, my bad.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl `i % 0` would be dividing by zero... obviously this results in `NaN`.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, yes if `adList` was empty that would occur

Comment: That works.  I'm not really sure why, but it does, thanks.  I know about modulus, but never would have thought of inserting it there.

Comment: @Shmiddty: I wasn't quite sure which way around it was there for a second. Thank you for the re-assurance though and apologies for the mix-up. Either way, +1 for the answer `Gaby aka G .Petrioli`, nice solution.

Comment: @Steve Modulus is the **remainder** of a division operation. By definition, this means that the return value is limited to values between 0 and the denominator (never equaling the denominator).